# Study the convergence of the sequence defined by the sum of all modules of $\ z_n$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence, limits-without-lhopital

Let $\ z_n$ be a sequence.  There exists $\ m <> k$ with $\ m\geq 1$ and $\ k\leq\dfrac{n}{3}$ so that $\ z_m= \dfrac{{a_m}{z_m}+{a_k}{z_k}}{3}$, where the complex numbers of the sequence $\ a_n$ all have the module equal to 1. Study the convergence of the sequence defined by the sum of all modules of $\ z_n$. I am unable to find how to use the module of complex numbers here. Should I use the fact that $\ |m+n|<=|m|+|n|$? At least for the boundedness? How to solve it?

Comment: The description of the condition on $\{z_n\}$ is completely unclear.

Comment: I changed it in order to be more clear.

Comment: Are you sure it's not "for any $m\in\mathbb N_+$, there exists $1\leqslant k\leqslant\frac m3$ such that $z_m=\frac13(a_mz_m+a_kz_k)$"?

Comment: Yes I am pretty sure.